# Is there a way to update a specific entry in an ElasticSearch index through Titan?

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

Hi I am using Elastic Search along with Titan..

Right now I have a a mixed index on a specific property for a specific type of vertex:

```
PropertyKey textProp = mgmt.getPropertyKey(EntityProps.text);
VertexLabel entityClass = mgmt.getVertexLabel(VertexLabels.Entity);
mgmt.buildIndex("EntityTextFull", Vertex.class)
  .indexOnly(entityClass)
  .addKey(textProp)
  .buildMixedIndex("search");
```

The indexed key values are not unique.. I wonder if there is a way to update some  properties including the indexed property for a specific vertex and then somehow reindex this specific vertex against this specific index..

Thanks,
Michail

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially pick [_update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html) endpoint and do partial updates:

> Externally, it appears as though we are partially updating a document
>   in place. Internally, however, the update API simply manages the same
>   retrieve-change-reindex process that we have already described. The
>   difference is that this process happens within a shard, thus avoiding
>   the network overhead of multiple requests. By reducing the time
>   between the retrieve and reindex steps, we also reduce the likelihood
>   of there being conflicting changes from other processes.

I've no experience with Titan, but I suppose you could translate raw queries into it.

Comment: Thanks. Although I know how to query Elastic Search directly .. what I really wanted is when I do a partial update in Titan to have ElasticSearch be automatically updated.. There is integration for creation but I am looking for integration for updates..